# Read Synon2E Model List in AS400/RPG

Tags: ibm-midrange

I want to know if a synon model list can be read from AS400 program. I have some objects in a synon model list. I need to iterate each object in the list for performing some operations on the object.

Is it possible to do so? I believe there should be some physical file in as400 which holds data in the model list. If anyone knows this please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - 2E model lists are held as members in the YMDLLSTRFP file in the 2E model library.

Comment: do you think there should be a tag for Synon in StackOverflow?

Comment: You can tag stuff with "synon", but it's not an 'official' tag. Of course, a pedant might point out that Synon (the company AND the product) haven't been around since 1998.

Comment: many thanks for the reply, as I learnt my my first Synon under the guidance of JP, I still think of it as Synon, My understanding is that the company that originally developed it sold it on to others who re-branded it, I think it is now offiocially known as CA 2E, not sure for how long, it might be advisable to request a stackoverflow tag of Synon as most users will understand the term, Or mybe it should be tagged as "CA 2E"? I would be interested to hear your thoughts about this.